# Form Not Saving to PHP File

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following code. This is used on my admin panel for administrators to put their notes in so the other admins can read it. I don't want to store this in a database.

The issue is the form is not saving the text in the textarea.

```
<?php
IF (ISSET($_POST["submit"])) {
$string = '<?php 
$notes = "'. $_POST["notes"]. '";
?>';

$fp = FOPEN("includes/notes.php", "w");
FWRITE($fp, $string);
FCLOSE($fp);
echo '<div class="ok">' . $lang["done"] . '</div>';
}

include("includes/notes.php");
?>
<form action="" method="post" id="notesform">
<textarea placeholder="Admin notes" class="notes" id="notes"><?php echo $notes; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

What is going wrong? How can I fix this? I have tried most suggestions on Google but it keeps happening!

Comment: Change `<input type="submit" value="OK">` to `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">` then you first IF test will actually find the button name in `$_POST`

Comment: BTW: it is horrible to write the functions etc, in camelcase. Hard to read for other developers who could join your team etc.Think about it.

Comment: @bub you mean uppercase.. camelCase is just fine..

Comment: @MateiMihai yes thank you

Comment: @bub That's true, not all my code is uppercase. I took this script from the interwebs, that's why. I will convert it to lowercase, though. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not give `name` attribute to submit button.

When we submit a form to PHP, only elements get posted with a `name` attribute.

So, your code is not entering:

```
IF (ISSET($_POST["submit"])) { // Not satisfying this condition.
```

Corrected code:

```
<input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit">
```

Apply the same for text area also.

Comment: Ooooh of course! I tried adding that earlier to the `form` tag, but that didn't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pupil, is it possible here to get the text-area value without giving name="notes"?

Comment: Yes, @AmitRajput, you are correct. I will correct my answer. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Thanks...cheers!!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You had not given name="notes" to text-area and submit button name. Here is the complete correct code. Try this:

```
<?php
IF (ISSET($_POST["submit"])) {
$string = $_POST["notes"];

$fp = FOPEN("includes/notes.php", "w");
FWRITE($fp, $string);
FCLOSE($fp);
echo '<div class="ok">' . $lang["done"] . '</div>';
}

include("includes/notes.php");
?>
<form action="" method="post" id="notesform">
<textarea placeholder="Admin notes" class="notes" name="notes" id="notes"><?php echo $notes; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: @john is it works for you?

Comment: Yes, I got it working now, the guy above you was a little faster. Thanks for your help, though. It's appreciated

Comment: Thanks...cheers!!! :-)